# How to position items along the whole screen height while avoiding absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I have a div container with two subcontainers. The parent div should have a full height (from the top to the bottom of the screen). The first sub container should always be in the left center of that parent container. The second sub container should always be at the right bottom of that parent container.

[image]

First of all I tried to solve it using absolute positions

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#first {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="first">
    this is always on the left center of the screen
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    this is always on the right bottom of the screen
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought about avoiding absolute positions. Is there a way using flexbox/grid for this? I started with this

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#first {
  align-self: center;
}

#second {
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">
    this is always on the left center of the screen
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div>this is always on the right bottom of the screen</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see the first subcontainer seems to be fine. The second one is at the bottom of the container which looks good. But the content is not at the right bottom corner (you might have to click "Full page" to see it). Does someone know how to fix it? Maybe this snippet can be simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second div doesnt need to set display flex. Just set margin-left: auto; it should work as div is display block by default.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#first {
  align-self: center;
}

#second {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">
    this is always on the left center of the screen
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div>this is always on the right bottom of the screen</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid` to display 2 columns and `align-self: self-end` to push the second column to bottom.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

#second {
  align-self: self-end;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">
    this is always on the left center of the screen
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div>this is always on the right bottom of the screen</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but this does not solve my problem. the second container is not at bottom right

Comment: Well. it does.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ6YX.png

Comment: I got it, you mean it should be also aligned.. I've updated the answer (although I saw that you already accepted an answer)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you need to set these rules to the `html, body` tags:

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And the parent container has a `height: 100%`. I have given two solutions with `absolute` positioning and `flexbox`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#first {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    this is always on the left center of the screen
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    this is always on the right bottom of the screen
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution with `flex` and `margin`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#first {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

#second {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    this is always on the left center of the screen
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    this is always on the right bottom of the screen
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Side Note:** Don't use `IDs` for styling.

### Code Explanation:

- `100vw` and `100vh` for the `parent` wrapper to give it full width & height.
- `align-items: center` alongside `display: flex` to vertically center all children (mainly, our `left-center` child)
- For the `right-bottom` child, we give it an `absolute` position with `right: 0` and `bottom: 0` to stick it to the corner (Don't forget `position: relative` to its parent to avoid overlapping if you've other elements on the page)

Here's a working snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.left-center {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

.right-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-center"></div>
  <div class="right-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But my question was if there's a way to avoid absolute stylings